# NSTextView subview do not displayed when drawsBackground = false

Tags: macos, swift, appkit, osx-yosemite

1. Add NSTextView (either by hand or through Interface builder).
2. Set drawsBackground = false
3. Add subview directly to NSTextView

Subview will not be visible.

However, if I add another subview to the same level as, for example, NSScrollView, the first subview will appear.

Here is sample project for XCode: https://www.dropbox.com/s/inz30bq9xzdw0g5/TestTextSubviews.zip?dl=0

In the source code if you uncomment this lines:

//        let bg2 = BgView(frame: NSRect(x: 105, y: 105, width: 100, height: 100))
//        window.contentView.addSubview(bg2)

then first subview will appear too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact reason but suspect it is a view hierarchy issue. I created a new project from cocoa app template, added nstextview then added 1 then 2 of your subviews - seems to work as intended.  The cocoa app template setup with window controller and view controller so maybe this correctly sorts out a view hierarchy oddity that isn't obvious from directly adding a view to a window in a nib - Here is the sample project - https://www.dropbox.com/s/sef54sc2pgdws7f/NSTextViewAddSubviews.zip?dl=0

(NB: I'm on Xcode 7 beta at the moment but i don't think it should make any difference)